# On a Cisco switch, how do I see the difference between current VLAN settings and those that have been written to memory?

Tags: cisco

If a switch gets rebooted and the settings haven't been "wr"d, when it comes back up things will be all wrong. I want to see what the current vlan settings are vs what has been "wr"d.

Thanks!!

Edit:

Er... I meant like the difference between current
show int status
and what *will* get set if the switch gets rebooted. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
show running-config
```

and

```
show startup-config
```

Answer (score 3):

Show running-config vs. show startup-config.  As long as the switch is in vtp transparent mode the vlan info will show up.

Answer (score 0):

[Some IOSes](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/fundamentals/configuration/guide/cf_config-diff_ps6350_TSD_Products_Configuration_Guide_Chapter.html) have a diff tool included:

```
Router# show archive config differences running-config startup-config
+ip subnet-zero
+ip name-server 10.4.4.4
+voice dnis-map 1
 +dnis 111
interface Ethernet1/0
 +no ip address
 +shutdown
+ip default-gateway 10.5.5.5
+ip classless
+access-list 110 deny ip any host 10.1.1.1
+access-list 110 deny ip any host 10.1.1.2
+access-list 110 deny ip any host 10.1.1.3
+snmp-server community private RW
-no ip subnet-zero
interface Ethernet1/0
 -ip address 10.7.7.7 255.0.0.0
-no ip classless
-snmp-server community public RO
```